# Cannot send email attachment PDF with CakePHP Mail

Tags: php, email, cakephp, pdf

Anyone can help me please to solve this problem. Im trying to send PDF attachment with CakePHP. I think all thing should be work fine. But why I get email result like in screenshoot?

[image]

My code to send pdf:

```
function send_notif_email($email=null,$template='default',$data=null,$subject='Notification',$noreplay=true,$attachment=array()) {
    $Email = new CakeEmail('default');
    $emailData = $data;

    if($Email->template($template)
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->to($email)
    ->from(($noreplay == true)?Configure::read('Meta.noreplay'):Configure::read('Meta.email'))
    ->replyTo(($noreplay == true)?Configure::read('Meta.noreplay'):Configure::read('Meta.email'))
    ->setHeaders(array(
        'From' => ($noreplay == true)?Configure::read('Meta.noreplay'):Configure::read('Meta.email'), 
        'Reply-To' => ($noreplay == true)?Configure::read('Meta.noreplay'):Configure::read('Meta.email'),
        'MIME-Version' => '1.0', 
        'Content-type' => 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1', 
    ))
    ->attachments($attachment)
    ->subject($subject)
    ->viewVars(compact('emailData')) /*set data*/
    ->send()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I just check all attachment array and filepath, all is fine:

```
array(
        'penawaran_0001_VN_SPN_X_2015' => '/home3/salesku/public_html/penawaran-online/app/webroot/upload/offer/00001/penawaran_0001_VN_SPN_X_2015.pdf',
        'X100.pdf' => '/home3/salesku/public_html/penawaran-online/app/webroot/upload/attachment/00001/X100.pdf'
    )
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just found the problem.
It looks likely setHeader should removed from method send_notif_email.

Not its work with new code:

```
function send_notif_email($email=null,$template='default',$data=null,$subject='Notification',$noreplay=true,$attachment=array()) {
    $Email = new CakeEmail('default');
    $emailData = $data;

    if($Email->template($template)
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->to($email)
    ->from(($noreplay == true)?Configure::read('Meta.noreplay'):Configure::read('Meta.email'))
    ->replyTo(($noreplay == true)?Configure::read('Meta.noreplay'):Configure::read('Meta.email'))
    ->attachments($attachment)
    ->subject($subject)
    ->viewVars(compact('emailData')) /*set data*/
    ->send()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Thanks for all.